# i2c device only detecting when scanning limited range

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to use a [Raspberry Pi header](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/p/60/1-Wire-Pi-Plus). I've soldered the pins on the header and connected the board to the Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

I've followed the steps, as described here, to configure the Raspberry (enable i2c and 1-wire) and install the required tools (i2c-tools).

When running i2cdetect -l it displays the following:
`i2c-1   i2c   bcm283 I2C adapter   I2C adapter`.

When running i2cdetect -y 1 it displays all connections as '--'.

I've found out that when running i2detect -y 1 23 119 (where 23 is the start and 119 is the end of the probing range), it will indeed display '18' on row '10' column '8' as expected. If I use a lower, or no start number at all, it will not display the 18.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the J1 jumper to the Raspberry Pi header to overcome this issue. Works now!